Apply DB migrations to all postgres schemas starting with specific string
I am writing a Flask microservice that uses a postgresql database. I want to use 'flask migrate' (which is basically alembic) for DB migrations. As I am new to it, I am struggling a bit...
My problem:
The postgresql has one schema per tenant ("tenant_1", "tenant_2", ...). Each tenant should have the same tables like the shown item table:
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = (
    "postgresql+psycopg2://..."
)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    col_1 = db.Column(db.Text)
    col_2 = db.Column(db.Text)

With the default 'env.py' of Alembic, the item table is created in public schema (flask db migrate -m "Initial migration.").
But I want to apply the item DB migration to all tenants.

Changing env.py like this:
def run_migrations_online():
    ...
    connectable = get_engine()
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=get_metadata(),
            **conf_args,
        )
        with context.begin_transaction():
            # Here starts the custom part
            for tenant in ["tenant_123", "tenant_537"]: # Will be replaced by list from DB
                context.execute(text(f"SET search_path = {tenant}, public;"))
                context.run_migrations()

Works when I already have a DB migration script. However, with this change I cannot generate new DB migrations. It's telling me:
ValueError: This MigrationScript instance has a multiple-entry list for UpgradeOps; please use the upgrade_ops_list attribute.

(I think because I call run_migrations() twice?)

Changing env.py like this:
def run_migrations_online():
    ...
    connectable = get_engine()
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        for tenant in ["tenant_123", "tenant_537"]: # Will be replaced by list from DB
            conn = connection.execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: tenant})
            logger.info("Migrating tenant schema %s" % tenant)
            context.configure(
                connection=conn,
                target_metadata=get_metadata(),
                **conf_args,
            )
            with context.begin_transaction():
                context.run_migrations()

Same as above. Works when I already have a DB migration script. Cannot generate one because of:
ValueError: This MigrationScript instance has a multiple-entry list for UpgradeOps; please use the upgrade_ops_list attribute."



I think best would be to set a special "tenant_blueprint" schema in the Python code and then translate the schema "tenant_blueprint" whenever an upgrade is done. Then I could also handle tables that are not within a tenant's scope. But how do I do this?
